# How to open a location's 'native' info window with Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my first time using the Google Maps API. I want to display a location and instead of having to create a custom marker and infowindow at a latitude and longitude, I'd like to actually open the info window you get when you do a simple google maps search.

Right now I'm basically using the infowindow as described in the google maps documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Here is a picture of what I'd like my map to look like when I load it:
[image]

EDIT: in case some of you don't understand for some reason, I want to display the infowindow that's displayed in the picture. Basically if you did a google maps search for some location and the marker popped up with rating, website, phone number, address, etc.

SOLUTION: Actually it's **really** easy. No API required. You can use this code sample I found: http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/google-maps-contact-info

Answer (score 0):

To have infowindow open on load add

```
infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

as last line in

```
initialize()
```

This is for documented code.

Comment: I know how to open an infowindow. The problem is, in the google maps developer guide, the infowindow is custom made, with it's own html. Instead of manually entering my own html into a custom infowindow, I'd like to open the info window that is populated by google (the one in the picture, with ratings, website, picture, etc).

Comment: @user1080952  As this is a different question to that asked either EDIT question or write a new question